# SQL Query for multiple rows

Tags: mysql, query

Good day. I'm trying and failing to write a mySql query that will return custid only if that custid has multiple values. In the example data below I want to return custid only for customers with type 2,5 & 7 set so only custid   1440 in the result. Can anyone help?

| custid | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1436 | 7 |
| 1436 | 5 |
| 1437 | 2 |
| 1438 | 2 |
| 1439 | 5 |
| 1440 | 2 |
| 1440 | 5 |
| 1440 | 7 |
| 1441 | 2 |
| 1441 | 5 |
| 1442 | 7 |
| 1443 | 5 |
| 1444 | 7 |

Many Thanks.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `HAVING COUNT` condition `=3` and `type in (2,5,7)` to produce your expected result.

Try:

```
SELECT custid
FROM test_tbl
WHERE type in (2,5,7)
GROUP BY custid
HAVING COUNT(custid)=3;
```

DEMO: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qff694udysNgqbyJyFcDzn/7

Comment: Many Thanks Ergest